# the weak form of 'on'

Tags: pronunciation, fast-speech-rules, weak-forms

I am confused at whether or not there is a weak form at preposition's 'ON'.
I've checked at some dictionaries at Cambridge and Oxford dictionary, they don't mention on the weak form's pronunciation.
However, I, am a Japanese, checked at English-Japanese dictionaries, they mention on the weak form as /ən/.

For example, is there the difference of pronunciation between 'It goes on' and 'There is an apple on the table' in connected speech?

Does it exist?

Thanks
Yuichi

*It's Edited

Comment: Are you asking about the pronunciation difference when saying "What's going **on**?" and "It is **on** the table."?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Yes, I would like to ask what you said. Could you tell me if you know it. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. Can you try to edit your question? Your question is not clear.

Comment: In my speech (British), neither "in" nor "on" is ever reduced to /ən/, in any context, as far as I can observe. The vowel is probably centralised to some degree, but they remain distinct. "An" is often reduced to /ən/, however.

Comment: @Gandalf; 'to' and 'of' are regularly reduced to /tə/ and /əv/ in BrE. Aren't they in AmE?

Comment: @ColinFine my bad. I meant "on'. will strike or correct. thanks. The funny thing is, I just got done writing an answer explaining that very thing. Duh!

Comment: OED says the unstressed pronunciation is with a schwa but I'm not sure I can hear it with my ageing Londoner's ears except perhaps in "Not on your life!"

Comment: I suspect that, if you listen *very* carefully, you can detect some *minor* difference in stress on the word "on" in different contexts.  But I can think of no cases where this difference would be significant beyond the significance of stress in general as it relates to questioning, surprise, irritation, etc.

Comment: I'd definitely reduce it in *"one on one"*, *"out on a limb"* and some other phrases where *on* is a middle word. But usually it's not reduced. So does this count as a weak form? Or just idiomatic pronunciation of phrases?

Comment: As for your two examples, there's not much difference in pronunciation between *"it goes on"* and *"apple on the table"*. Certainly the second is not pronounced /ən/.

Comment: @PeterShor - I notice that I pronounce the two *slightly* differently (a bit more of an "uh" vs "oh" sound for the second, and it's just a hair "weaker" sounding).  But when I say "apples" instead then they're the same, so the difference is presumably due to the preceding sound.

Comment: I appreciate all of comments and an answer. I've checked the sound of one on one at http://youglish.com/. Most BrE speakers use /ɒ/ sound, but some speakers of them pronounce the different quality of /ɒ/. Also, GrE speaker spoke the different sound like /ʌ/ not /ə/.

Comment: @HotLicks Can Americans pronounce it /ən/ or /ʌn/? Thanks. vocaroo.com/i/s0fyj6xKCI7W

Comment: @Edinburgh1 - Certainly not the first --- that's "an".

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you. So if it's unstressed, it can be pronounced /ʌn/, right? Like in this voice recording: https://vocaroo.com/i/s0fyj6xKCI7W.

Answer (score 1):

Speakers of the various English dialects may disagree as to whether or not the prepositional use of "on" is stressed in their part of the world, Yuichi, but the important thing for you to remember is that such differences do occur.  So your dictionary is absolutely correct to prepare you for them.

The key factor, perhaps more so in American English, that determines whether a word is weak or stressed in individual speech is a matter of its importance to the speaker and/or its importance to the listener's understanding of the sentence.  For instance, "It goes on" employs "on" as an adverb, a part of speech that very typically takes high intonation in English, even more so when it distinguishes one phrasal verb from another.  Consider the differences between "Go up", "Go down" and "Go on" and you'll see just how important each final syllable is, which means that each of these words is usually stressed.

Now look at your other example, "There is an apple on the table".  In this sentence "on" is employed as a preposition to form the adverbial phrase "on the table" and while the entire phrase functions as an adverb, word stress among its three syllables may vary.  Everyone would agree that "the" takes a weak pronunciation, with "on" and "table" being more stressed, but the question is to what degree.

If someone is looking for the apple under the table, a speaker would likely say "No, it's ON the table", because "on" is now of greatest importance to the sentence.  However, if someone is looking on the kitchen counter, a speaker would probably say "No, it's on the TABLE", because "table" is now the operative word.

To complicate things further, many American speakers prefer to drop intonation over nonoperative words rather than place an "unnaturally" high stress over key words, so what becomes most relevant is the contrast among syllables, rather than the more traditional stress of syllables.  Hence "on the table" is very frequently pronounced in the US as "/ən/ the table", which confuses no one, since the apple could not possible be in the table.

Comment: Can Americans pronounce it /ən/ or /ʌn/? Thanks. vocaroo.com/i/s0fyj6xKCI7W

Answer (score 1):

If you reduce 'on', you get syllabic 'nn', which is the same as you get when you reduce 'in'. Since there are many contexts where either is possible, to avoid clashes, we refuse to reduce 'on': no matter how low the *stress*, the vowel *quality* will always remain.
Of course, we could have chosen to do this to 'in' instead. But it's a question of conserving energy, 'in' being much more common, and also a common prefix.
Contrary to what has been stated above, I don't think that *one on one* will have a reduced on because that can too easily be confused with *one and one*.
As an aside, Yuichi, I am impressed with how acutely Japanese speakers hear English, being able to distinguish subtle differences most native speakers miss.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for all dialects, but in my BrE, North London dialect, *on* is never reduced, although many other prepositions are (*for*, *of* and so forth). *Of* often becomes *əv* and *for* could easily become *fə*. But *on* is always *on*.

Interestingly, I cannot think of a single case of reduction of a high back vowel, although I can easily think of examples for other vowels.

Comment: Does of have any other pronunciation? If that's the weak form, what's the strong form ( in your dialect) ?

Comment: The strong form, for me, would be /ov/. Admittedly it doesn't turn up very often, but it turns up in stressed contexts, so if for example someone were to say "Humboldt university in Berlin", I'd correct them to "Humboldt University /ov/ Berlin"