# Is there dialectal variation in the weak form of "on"?

Tags: american-english, dialects, phonetics, weak-forms

This question is related, *but not quite identical,* [to a previous one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309167) and [to another similar one.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411368/can-on-be-reduced)

In a recent video, phonetician [Geoff Lindsey claimed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlbGtEg68x4&t=575s) that the words "off" and "on" do not have weak forms; see his [previous video on weak forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaXYas58_kc) for some background.

I claim that this is wrong, and that in fact some speakers (including myself) *do* reduce "on" to something like [ɪn] or [ən] or just [n], with the vowel sound absent or barely perceptible. Here are some examples on YouTube (found via YouGlish), though you will likely need to reduce the playback speed to make it more obvious:

- ["right on the table" (at 5:07)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jop-fO-yHx4&t=305s)
- ["guy on the phone" (at 42:20)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj2fpM57Z7A&t=2538s)
- ["sat on the couch" (at 1:09:40)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLjgJKIFzOQ&t=4180s)
- ["out on the porch" (at 1:20)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdlnJRzgIdk&t=80s)
- ["on a pedestal" (at 20:18)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-ixpxwYGzs&t=1218s)
- ["right on top of each other" (at 11:58)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=n5jXg_NNiCA&t=11m58s)

I don't think it's a coincidence that Geoff Lindsey is British, and that all of these speakers are (as far as I can tell) speaking American English. Geoff Lindsey does mention that weak forms may differ among accents, though he doesn't mention any exceptions in his discussion of "off" and "on." Presumably this isn't universal; it's probably also limited to cases where "on" can't be confused with "in" or "and."

Am I hearing these examples correctly? Is this indeed evidence for a weak form on "on," contra Geoff Lindsey? Is weakening "on" more common or acceptable in American English than in British English?

Comment: Your clips certainly sound a little odd to me, as a BrE speaker.

Comment: @KateBunting Interesting! I think the phrase "the guy on the phone" is the best example for me; when I say that out loud, the "on" is just [n].

Comment: Some sound natural and unremarkable to me; a few rather sound like they belong to specific accents.

Comment: To hear "just the n" at all, you need the schwa vowel -- a grunt or glottal stop. So the *on* becomes **uhn**. Like where "I'm going to" becomes *Munna*, the *gonna* becomes **un**.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Not really; /n/ is often pronounced as a syllabic consonant (like in the second syllable of "happen"); dictionaries pretend there's a schwa there, but the vowel usually isn't articulated separately (as I understand it). A glottal stop, of course, would not be a vowel.

Comment: Here's another relevant previous question: [Can "on" be reduced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/411368/can-on-be-reduced) One answer there claims, with no reference, that "On cannot be reduced to /ən/ in GA."

Comment: @herisson I've added a link to that, but I don't quite think it's a duplicate of my question and I don't think your answer really resolves the issue. Importantly, this isn't a question of how (pedagogically) you would teach non-native speakers; it's a question of pronunciation and usage by native speakers of different dialects.

Comment: @herisson I also think my examples establish that this reduction does at least sometimes happen in AmE, and that it's by no means limited to "fairly markedly casual styles of speaking," as the source you cited states.

Comment: In American English, ***all*** monosyllabic prepositions have a vast range of "weakening", ranging from odd vowels, loss of consonants, centralization to schwa, or a grunt, or a modified following consonant, or complete deletion. Nobody always pronounces them the same, and different people have different habits. You need a sociological dialect survey with phonetic, locational, economic, and social parameters to answer a question like this. Plus spectrograms, and statistics. It's very expensive, but nobody really wants to find out.

Comment: @alphabet Much of linguistics is formal and doesn't deal with real variation or phonetic data. A formalist is usually defining binary distinctions instead of multivariate systems. And linguists do argue, especially about Official Designations, which are sort of like academic gang colors.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would doubt alphabet's first hypothesis. A few seconds before the last example, of the tech watch, there are two clear instances of the same speaker using the 'standard' longer form of 'on'. Don't the three together illustrate how, often, the weight of pronunciation follows the importance of the sound in sentence. British English does very much the same; exactly the same in all alphabet's examples.

Comment: It seems like "on" and "in" can be pronounced more or less identically, but they're either differentiable by context or in many cases it doesn't matter which preposition is used.

Comment: As @ John Lawler seems to me to be implying, it seems overdoing things to describe variations in pronunciation as differences of "form".  For example, it has been demonstrated by long term review of recordings that the British royal family, including King Charles and his sister and even the late Queen Elizabeth, have gradually (not deliberately) modified their once striking royal/upper class accents closer to what is sometimes called 'BBC English'.  The variation I hear is one of emphasis between "I turned ón my computer" and "I túrned on my attacker."